# Do I always have to specify an index array to a Renderable in libGDX?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

Right now I have a project set up with 2 meshes, which are rendering correctly by themselves.

My Objective is to add lighting to one of them(a surface I want to display), which is made up from `GL10_GL_TRIANGLES`, but not the other(a helper grid), which is (obviously) made up from `GL10.GL_LINES`.

So far I managed to compile the 2 into renderables, like so:

```
    grid.mesh.setVertices(gridMeshArray);
    grid.meshPartOffset = 0;
    grid.meshPartSize = grid.mesh.getNumIndices();
    grid.primitiveType = GL10.GL_LINES;
    grid.material = new Material();
    grid.bones = null;

    sampleSurface.mesh.setVertices(meshVArray);
    sampleSurface.mesh.setIndices(meshIArray);
    sampleSurface.meshPartOffset = 0;
    sampleSurface.meshPartSize = sampleSurface.mesh.getNumIndices();
    sampleSurface.primitiveType = GL10.GL_TRIANGLES;
    sampleSurface.material = new Material();
    sampleSurface.bones = null;
```

When I run the program, I see the sampleSurface, but not the grid.
Rendering is as follows:

```
    MB.begin(cam.getCam());
        MB.render(sampleSurface);
        MB.render(grid);
    MB.end();
```

It's propably worth to mention, that I'm not using any shaders right now, just the command:

```
    cam.apply(Gdx.gl10);
```

Which is'nt the best practice, and I'm planning to replace it once I have the time to dwelve into the topic.

My guess is, the grids won't display, because  I didn't specify an index array to them. That seems to be the only difference between the two renderables. (not counting the environment, since changing `grid.environment` didn't have any effect.)

Defining an index array seems highly illogical for the grid, since it doesn't really have overlapping vertices. I'm not sure what to do, or where lies the problem, since the 2 meshes draw perfectly by themselves. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/Renderable.html#meshPartSize
The `#meshPartSize` member of `Renderable` is used to specify the size (in vertices) of the part of the mesh to render. When not rendering a strip this the number of primitives multiplied by the number of vertices per primitive. So if you want to render 4 triangles (GL_TRIANGLES), then the size is 12 (4 triangles * 3 vertices = 12 vertices total). If you want to render 12 lines (GL_LINES), then the size is 24 (12 lines * 2 vertices = 24 vertices total).

In practice this means that, if the mesh is indexed, the size is equal to the number of indices you want to render. If the mesh isn't indexed, then it's equal to the number vertices you want to render. A mesh is considered indexed if the number of indices it contains is greater than zero (`mesh.getNumIndices() > 0`).

To be specifc: if indexed then `glDrawElements` will be used with the offset and count arguments as specified. Otherwise `glDrawArrays` will be used with the offset and count arguments as specified.

That being said: please note that some classes might require indexed meshes, also note that GLES1.x might not be fully supported. So in practice it is advised to use indexed meshes and GLES2.

Comment: Wow thank you for the swift answer!this cleared up quite a bit! After reading your answer I realized what my error was.

Answer (score 1):

After a refreshing beer and a walk I read @Xoppa's answer, and it made me see my error.

Simply changing

`grid.meshPartSize = grid.mesh.getNumIndices();`

to

`grid.meshPartSize = grid.mesh.getNumVertices();`

solved my problem, now it displays correctly.